# Checking a specific module installed or not in prestashop 1.6 , after installed then use overided front controller else core indexcontroller?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

if mymodule is installed then use overrided front controller else use core controller..
i just find the code to check the module is installed or not

```
if (Module::isInstalled(modulenamelowercase))
{
  Module::disableByName($this->name);   //note during testing if this is   not done, your module will show as installed in modules
  die(Tools::displayError('You must first un-install Module xxxx'));
}
```

Where all these checkings are to be done ??
Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: hello  friend i got the answer.. 
we can also place override inside the module.. 
like create folder structure inside module like 
yourmodulename/overide/controller/front/
and place main overide here and solve problem....


the question its self is irrelevant.
thanks for the support...

Comment: then please close it.